# How to send parameter to function only if statement is matched?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, stdmap

I have a map, that I only want to send to a function if it has elements in it. The function takes a parameter pack so I can send how many or how few elements I want.

Is there a way to make the size-check of the map in the call itself? There are a lot of maps that will be sent in the same call meaning that it would be very tedious to do the check outside of the call itself.

pseudo-code of what I want:

```cpp
std::map<int, int> a;
std::map<int, int> b;
std::map<int, int> c;
std::map<int, int> d;
fun( (if (a.size() > 0), (if (b.size() > 0), (if (c.size() > 0), (if (d.size() > 0));
```

I know this code is very wrong, but it is just to give you an idea of what I am after.

Comment: What do you mean with "send"? Please give a more complete example, at least with prototypes. I think you are trying to optimize the wrong way. The function can easily check if the map is empty and just return.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Call 0-argument `fun` or call 1-argument `fun` overload? This question needs more details, currently it looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: The usual way to *pass* a container to a function is to pass a range by using a pair of iterators. If you pass e.g. `a.begin()` and `e.end()` to the function, then it could easily check if the beginning iterator is equal to the end iterator, which means the range (container) is "empty" and just return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can for example pass the maps in a `std::initalizer_list` (or `std::vector`, whatever you prefer). And then inside the function `a()` loop over each map and check if it was empty:

```
#include <initializer_list
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

void a(std::initializer_list<std::map<int, int>> maps)
{
    for (const auto& m : maps) {
        if (m.empty()) {
            std::cout << "was empty\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "was not empty\n";
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> foo1;
    std::map<int, int> foo2;
    std::map<int, int> foo3;
    std::map<int, int> foo4;

    foo1[5] = 1;
    foo2[9] = 3;

    a({foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4});

    return 0;
}
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> was not empty
> was not empty
> was empty
> was empty
> ```

[**See it live**](https://onlinegdb.com/BJxX9o6fH)

Answer (score 2):

> The function takes a parameter pack so I can send how many or how few
>   elements I want. Is there a way to make the size-check of the map in
>   the call itself?

Other than using the helper function with `std::initalizer_list`, one can use good old (recursive)variadic templates for this. Simply provide a helper `func` which takes the parameter pack of maps which you want to pass the original `func`.

```
namespace helper
{
    void func() {}  // base case

    template <typename Map0, typename... Maps>
    void func(const Map0& firstMap, const Maps& ... restMaps)
    {
        if (!firstMap.empty()) {
            // not empty case: call ::func(firstMap); here
        }
        helper::func(restMaps...); // do check for the rest of the map
    }
}
```

This makes the function call to be:

```
std::map<int, int> a, b, c, d;
helper::func(a, b, c, d);
```

### ([See-online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CuR1lVVYMpvyJ6KD))